# How to Handle Events of User Control Grid View?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, user-controls

I Have a user control as a grid view.
I am adding it dynamically...i have made the method for data source but i am unable to use others events of grid view like **"Row_Data_Bound"** etc.

I have seen the code on net which says create delegates and add following

```
protected void Simple_DGV_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)   
{
OnRowDataBound(e);
}
```

but i get an error here saying **The name OnRowDataBound does not exist in the current context**

Can anyone help me out with accessing the events of user control grid view in the parent page

EDIT:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="ProjectManagement.UserControl.User1" %>
<div>
<asp:GridView ID="ucGridView" runat="server" SkinID="gvSchedulerSkin" AllowSorting="false" OnRowDataBound="ucGridView_RowDataBound">
   <RowStyle Width="20px" /> 
</asp:GridView>
</div>
```

this is my ascx page...i want to use this grid view at more than one place(at run time) so i have created a user-control...
Basically i want to call this user control from my code behind and then using its rowdatabound i want to data to be bind with the gridview..

i saw on websites it says use events bubbling...but i do not know how to implement that.

so can u help in that matter..so that i can use rowdatabound normally as i do

thnx in advance

Comment: Where is OnRowDataBound declared? If you've taken this from an example then you need the code for that method. Otherwise just put the code for whatever you need to do in the Simple_DGV_RowDataBound method itself.

Comment: I have seen the code here
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19345/Event-handling-in-a-Gridview-User-Control

Comment: actually i want to access RowDataBound of created gridview..but as my grid view is user control i need to define rowdatabound...how do i do it?

Comment: if you look at Step 8. of the code project you can see the implementation of the method you need!  Also, do you mean you have a usercontrol that contains a GridView? Or your usercontrol is a GridView but you've inherited from GridView to create your own.

Comment: edited my question...hope now its clear

Comment: Do you have a method called "ucGridView_RowDataBound" in the code behind your ucGridView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a project locally and this is ok.

I've a control called TestUserControl.ascx. I dragged a GridView control onto the user control in design mode and called it "grdControlsGrid".

This generated the below mark up.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="TestASPNet.TestUserControl" %>
<asp:GridView ID="grdControlsGrid" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
```

Then I added the event OnRowDataBound by typing "OnRowDataBound=" to the hmtl after runat="server". When you hit equals it gives you the option to create the method for this event. Double click the "Create method" option and this will wire up the event to the method for you.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="TestASPNet.TestUserControl" %>
<asp:GridView ID="grdControlsGrid" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="grdControlsGrid_OnRowDataBound">
</asp:GridView>
```

This code now resides in your user control as per the code below.

Alternatively you can wire the event up yourself in the users controls load.

```
 public partial class TestUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Manually Add event handler
            grdControlsGrid.RowDataBound += GrdControlsGrid_RowDataBound;
        }

        private void GrdControlsGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            //Manually bound event
        }

        protected void grdControlsGrid_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            //Auto wired event
        }
    }
```

for some reason when auto wiring via the markup you get the event "OnRowDataBound".. but when done in the code behind manually you get "RowDataBound". my guess is that they are one of the same.. but maybe someone else can shed light on that.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes i was i also searching through the net...then luckily just now got the logic to work.
If someone wants the control to load dynamically then they should use the alternative method as we wont create a hard coded control.
Thanks for ur efforts

Comment: @rk - No problem. Glad you found a solution. Cheers